# Loop through multiple datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my windows form, I am having 10 datagridview. They are exactly same, I mean columns are exactly same.
The ids are like myGrid1,myGrid2, myGrid3, myGrid4.....myGrid10.
Now I want to loop through all datagridview at once.

```
string prodName = "";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      {
             foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in myGrid[i].Rows)
             {
              prodName += dr.Cells["ProductName"].Value
             }
      }
```

but myGrid[i] doesn't exists obviously.
I can loop each datagridview seperately but is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: `var grid = this.Controls.Find(string.Format("myGrid{0}", i), true).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;`

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in grid.Rows) doesn't work

Comment: Pay attention to the cast: `as DataGridView`

Comment: DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)this.Controls.Find(string.Format("myGrid{0}", i), true).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Yup that works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (x is DataGridView)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in (DataGridView(x)).Rows)
        {
            prodName += dr.Cells["ProductName"].Value
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach ( DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>()) 
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
    {
        prodName += dr.Cells["ProductName"].Value
    }
}
```